# Access 2010 VBA IDE watch window graphics bug

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I'm experiencing a weird issue with the watch window. When I first set a watch the details appear just fine, but in break mode as soon as I advance (F5 / F8) the text changes to white, please see attached image. If I click back into the watch window the variables appear again. Obviously this is quite frustrating!

[image]

I'm on Access 2010 with Windows 7 Professional SP1. Any ideas on how to solve this? I've asked the IT guys here at work but they seem quite stumped.

Many thanks.

Comment: Yeah that is annoying! As a workaround, you could use debug.print to get some data out...

Comment: Yeah, I do that sometimes but printing something like an array or dictionary is a pain in the ***!